# How to get line-breaking / multirow to work in my beginner's table?

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx, multirow

I can't seem to get the `multirow` or `pbox` to give me a line break (of "automatic" width). The following won't compile successfully: note the two variations in the "TOTALLY" line. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{this is my first table's captive caption}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}} \toprule
× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \pbox[t]{1.5cm}{Bonjour monde!} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
% × & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \multirow{2}*{4000 apples and pears \\ and whatnot} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
DDD 1 & 47.6 & 29.1 & 1.0 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 15.2 & 0.0\\
UUU & 24.8 & 10.8 & 6.4 & 0.0 & 3.2 & 4.5 & 0.0\\
× & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
Unweighted average: & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
BBB & 33.8 & 11.3 & 9.1 & 0.4 & 1.8 & 11.0 & 0.2\\
GGG & 32.9904 & 8.60325 & 9.3845 & 0.0495 & 1.43225 & 10.79525 & 0.119\\
DDD & 39.4545 & 9.8695 & 15.3365 & 0.6915 & 2.246 & 10.6705 & 0.5105\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note ...
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

related (but didn't help me, yet):

- [Text wrapping in multirow columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/text-wrapping-in-multirow-columns?lq=1)
- [Newline in \multirow environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63746/newline-in-multirow-environment)
- [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

so this question is probably just yet-another-beginner's-desperate-duplicate... plz forgive!

**Edit**

just to supply a **working example** (for a quick comparison, note I got rid of the `\\` in the uncommented "TOTALLY" line):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{this is my first table's captive caption}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}} \toprule
× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & {4000 apples and pears and whatnot} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
%× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & {4000 apples and pears \\ and whatnot} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
% × & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \pbox[t]{1.5cm}{Bonjour monde!} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
% × & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & {\multirow{2}*{\pbox[t]{1.5cm}{Bonjour monde!}}} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
DDD 1 & 47.6 & 29.1 & 1.0 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 15.2 & 0.0\\
UUU & 24.8 & 10.8 & 6.4 & 0.0 & 3.2 & 4.5 & 0.0\\
× & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
Unweighted average: & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
BBB & 33.8 & 11.3 & 9.1 & 0.4 & 1.8 & 11.0 & 0.2\\
GGG & 32.9904 & 8.60325 & 9.3845 & 0.0495 & 1.43225 & 10.79525 & 0.119\\
DDD & 39.4545 & 9.8695 & 15.3365 & 0.6915 & 2.246 & 10.6705 & 0.5105\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note ...
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: from the `multirow` manual: `If the width was set explicitly, the text will be set in a   \parbox of that width; you can use \\ to force linebreaks where you like.` Is there a conflict to the other packages, e.g. `siunitx` ?

Comment: this works: `× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{Principal actor in rule adoption process}} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule`; so maybe its a problem specific to **`pbox`** vs. **???**

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You have a utf08 times in the first row but had not declared any encoding so this was being silently dropped, I added

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{textcomp}
```

so it worked, then easiest way to get a multi-line heading is to use `\multicolumn{1}` to get out of `S` and then nest a `tabular` (I probably should have used `\begin{tabular}[t]` but the image shows the default vertically centred arrangement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=1, add-decimal-zero=true, add-integer-zero=true, round-integer-to-decimal}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{this is my first table's captive caption}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{L}*{6}{S[table-format=3.2]}@{}} \toprule
× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Bonjour\tabularnewline monde!\end{tabular}} &
 {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
% × & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \multirow{2}*{4000 apples and pears \\ and whatnot} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
DDD 1 & 47.6 & 29.1 & 1.0 & 0.2 & 1.9 & 15.2 & 0.0\\
UUU & 24.8 & 10.8 & 6.4 & 0.0 & 3.2 & 4.5 & 0.0\\
× & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
Unweighted average: & × & × & × & × & × & × & ×\\
BBB & 33.8 & 11.3 & 9.1 & 0.4 & 1.8 & 11.0 & 0.2\\
GGG & 32.9904 & 8.60325 & 9.3845 & 0.0495 & 1.43225 & 10.79525 & 0.119\\
DDD & 39.4545 & 9.8695 & 15.3365 & 0.6915 & 2.246 & 10.6705 & 0.5105\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [1] the first note ...
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: regarding \\ vs \tabularnewline: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78796/difference-between-and-tabularnewline

Comment: Regarding pbox _vs_ parbox: Why does `× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{Principal actor in rule adoption process}} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule
` work, while `× & TOTALLY bla percentage of bla & {1000} & {2000} & {3000} & \multirow{2}{*}{\pbox{2cm}{Principal actor in rule adoption process}} & {5000} & {6000\tnote{1}}\\ \midrule` fails?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I don't know. pbox is  rather fragile I suspect (I've never used it)

Comment: How could I make the second line [smaller](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56008/different-sizes-of-font-available-in-table) - or even better: _narrower_ (as in "horizontally squashed" text)? That's "**monde!"** in our example. Would I need to use [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Column_specification_using_.3E.7B.5Ccmd.7D_and_.3C.7B.5Ccmd.7D) from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array ? If so, how? Else, what other (sensible) options would there be?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty `\small monde!` (also it's best not to ask followup questions in the comments, best to ask new questions)